# Updating a set of documents from a list of key value pairs

Tags: mongodb

I'm looking to see if there's a better way of performing this certain type of batch update.

If I have a list or map of `_id`'s and `values`, such that:

```
var updates = [
  {_id: "abc", field: 12},
  {_id: "abd", field: 32},
  {_id: "xyz", field: 22},
  // ... snip (100 or more records) ...
}
```

And I'd like to update `myCollection` with the new value for `field` on each document listed, eg:

```
var update;
for (var i = 0; i < updates.length; i++){
   update = updates[i];
   db.myCollection.update({_id: update._id}, {$set: {field: update.field}});
}
```

But this seems archaic as it has to round-trip each query to the server one by one.

In SQL I would avoid the extra round trips by doing a single query (Or use temporary tables):

```
WITH batch_update (_id uuid, value int) as (
  VALUES (...)
);
UPDATE my_table
SET
   value = bu.value
FROM 
   batch_update as bu
WHERE
   bu._id = my_table._id;
```

So. Is there a better way to achieve this result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Bulk](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/) API to achieve this.

```
var updates = [{"_id": "abc", "field": 12},
              {"_id": "abd", "field": 32},
              {"_id": "xyz", "field": 22}];
var bulk = db.myCollection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
var update = undefined;
for (var i = 0; i < updates.length; i++){
    update = updates[i];
    bulk.find( {_id: update._id} ).update( {$set: {field: update.field}} );
}
bulk.execute();
```

Further you can add logic to call `bulk.execute()` once every 100 records or so.